# How to put math symbols instead of text in the brackets under different parts of the equation

Tags: math-mode

to write text in the bracket under different parts of a equation, we can use

```
 \underbrace{a + b}_\text{text 1}.
```

However, when I put math `\bar{w}` as text,  it returns error:

```
  \underbrace{a + b}_\text{\bar{w}}
```

does not work. Any good suggestions?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  just omit the `\text: `\underbrace{a + b}_{\bar{w}}`

Comment: Funny, one would have thought the converse would be problematic....

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but I think it is risky to get accustomed to writing such thing as `..._\text{...}`: the recommended form is always `..._{\text{...}}`, _i.e._, to include the *whole* subscript in its own pair of braces.

Answer (score 3):

`\bar` is a math accent, so the `\text` is neither necessary nor correct.  remove it:

```
\underbrace{a + b}_{\bar{w}}
```

also, if it *is* required to put text into a sub- or superscript, it should be enclosed in braces:

```
\underbrace{a + b}_{\text{...}}
```